# Different array name to "x" different arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm traying to create x amount of arrays, each one called `square(number)=new Array...`.

```
int numberofsquares=1;
int prgrm=0;
int amount=0;
int v=1;
    while(prgrm==0) {
    System.out.println("Enter another square? (y/n)");
    if (stdin.next().startsWith("y")) {
        List<String> square(x) = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(amount!=3)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter: ");
            square(x).add("1,"+v+","+stdin.next());
            v++;
            amount++;
            System.out.println(firstsquare);
        }
        amount=0;
        v=1;

        while(amount!=3)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter: ");
            square(x).add("2,"+v+","+stdin.next());
            v++;
            amount++;
            System.out.println(firstsquare);
        }
        amount=0;
        v=1;

        while(amount!=3)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter: ");
            square(x).add("3,"+v+","+stdin.next());
            v++;
            amount++;
            System.out.println(firstsquare);
        }
        amount=0;
        v=1;
    }  else {
        prgrm++;
    }
}
if (prgrm==1) {
    System.out.println("Finish");
}
```

So the first time you press `y` the array that creates is called `square1`, the next one `square2`,`squre3`...

How can I do this? Thanks :D

Comment: you can't. you can, however, create a List in which each element is a List<String>, so instead of the number being in the name, it'll be the index in the containing List

Comment: Use a list of lists.

Comment: use `List<List<String>>`

Comment: I've modified it becouse i thought that i didn't explain what i want clearly.

Comment: @AlbertoTeixidó  Are you sure about updated code? Because `amount=0;` is set and being check in while for non-zero value e.g. `while(amount!=3)`. Also `v=1;` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No*, You can't create variable names dynamically.
But if your intention is to create different storage space then you can use `List<List<String>>`(as mentioned already) and can access each element using [get() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)).

Following is an working example. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/zpwFYd):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    try(Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
            int numberofsquares=1;
            int prgrm=0;
            int v=1;
            List<List<String>> square = new ArrayList<>();
            while(prgrm==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter another square? (y/n)");
                if (stdin.next().startsWith("y"))
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                    {
                        square.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                        //Get last element's index
                        int lastIndex = square.size()-1;
                        //Get last element and add a String
                        square.get(lastIndex).add((i+1) +","+v+","+stdin.next());
                        v++;
                    }
                } 

                else
                {
                    prgrm++;
                }
            }
            if (prgrm==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Finish");
            }
            System.out.println("Lists are: " + square);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how are the arrays called??

Comment: @AlbertoTeixidó I have updated the answer after your update in question. Comment if still there is still any problem. Also, please read my comment on your question.

Comment: Okay, so, you didn't answered exactly my question, but by your aportation i've solved it. ty

Comment: @AlbertoTeixidó If your problem is solved then upvote and accept the answer to consider that it is _Answered_.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested lists, eg:

```
List<List<String>> squares = new ArrayList<>();
```